# Programmatically add MultiTrigger to ContentControl sub-class

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

Everything works fine until I call this.Triggers.Add(TriggerFocus).
This class sub-classes ContentControl.

Here's my code:

```
private void CreateTriggers()
    {
        TriggerFocus = new MultiTrigger
        {
            Conditions = 
            {
                new Condition
                {
                    Property = IsFocusedProperty,
                    Value = true
                },
                new Condition
                {                                                    
                    Property = IsKeyboardFocusedProperty,
                    Value = true
                }
            },
            Setters =
            {
                new Setter
                {
                    Property = SetFocusProperty,
                    Value = true
                },
            }
        };

        this.Triggers.Add(TriggerFocus);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Here's the equivalent xaml which also throws an error:

```
<ContentControl.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="ContentControl.IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="ContentControl.IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="BorderFocus" Property="ContentControl.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ContentControl.Triggers>
```

After some testing I have isolated the problem to the MultiTrigger above. It seems to work fine if I put the trigger in a template or style.

The error thrown is not very informative:
Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl' threw an exception

Comment: Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl' threw an exception which basically tells me nothing ;(

Answer (score 0):

You can put only EventTriggers into `<ContentControl.Triggers>` collection.